# Angular 5 Material Table With Paginator in Tab is Blank Until Change

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, tabs, material-design

I copied the Material example table into one of my tabs of my app. If I add pagination to the table it will initially display as empty until I click a new page or page size.

This makes sense as the documentation says "Set the paginator after the view init since this component will be able to query its view for the initialized paginator." but I was wondering on what are the best practices for initializing a table inside of a tab so that I could use the paginator.

Thanks!

Code:
HTML

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Code: TS

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Table with pagination
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-pagination-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-pagination-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-pagination-example.html',
})
export class TablePaginationExample {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  /**
   * Set the paginator after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized paginator.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue while trying to use mat-pagination in combination with the traditional data table as by default the page size was undefined and then I was looking at the documentation and found that page Event is emitted when the paginator changes the page size or page index, so I created a behavior subject with the default values like:

```
paginationDetail = new BehaviorSubject(
{
 length: 10,
 pageIndex: 0,
 pageSize: 10
});
```

And then, in you HTML you can add event listner on the mat-paginator like:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
             (page)="getUpdate($event)"
             [pageSize]="10"
             [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
</mat-paginator>
```

This getUpdate method will be called on each change in the pagination, so we can replace the default value of the behaviorSubject with the new value like:

```
getUpdate(event) {
  this.paginationDetail.next(event);
}
```

You can use this behaviorSubject to get the latest value on the pagination. So the basic idea is to assign the default values until you get the update triggered from the pagination.
Again this solution is if you use mat-pagination with traditional data table. If using mat-table I dont think so you should have any problem with direct assignment of this.myDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem had result so:

```
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
```

and add

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
```

}